# In Yosys I am getting a Warning saying Literal has a width of 8 bit, can anyone elaborate on it

Tags: warnings, fpga, literals, formal-verification, yosys

In Yosys  I am getting a Warning saying Literal has a width of 8 bit, can anyone elaborate on it since i am new to yosys and I could not find any resource to understand the reason for the warning.

below is the warnings from yosys:

Warning: Literal has a width of 8 bit, but value requires 16 bit. (../FPGA_memory/ROM_FPGA.v:1)

Warning: Literal has a width of 8 bit, but value requires 12 bit. (../FPGA_memory/ROM_FPGA.v:1)

Warning: Literal has a width of 8 bit, but value requires 12 bit. (../FPGA_memory/ROM_FPGA.v:1)

Warning: Literal has a width of 8 bit, but value requires 20 bit. (../FPGA_memory/ROM_FPGA.v:1)

Warning: Literal has a width of 8 bit, but value requires 16 bit. (../FPGA_memory/ROM_FPGA.v:1)

Comment: Please provide the file causing the problem, or even better a MCVE (minimum complete verifiable example)

Comment: I figured it out, it was due to register "mem" initialisation using $readmemh("box.mif",mem,0,255); then I replaced it with $readmemh("box.mem",mem);. This line resolved the warning.

"box.mem" file was created as explained in 
https://projectf.io/posts/initialize-memory-in-verilog/#:~:text=Verilog%20Syntax,%24readmemb(%22bin_memory_file.

I created this .mif from altera quartus IDE but was not aware It can not be used in $readmemh.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it was due to register "mem" initialisation using $readmemh("box.mif",mem,0,255); then I replaced it with $readmemh("box.mem",mem);. This line resolved the warning.

"box.mem" file was created as explained in
https://projectf.io/posts/initialize-memory-in-verilog/#:~:text=Verilog%20Syntax,%24readmemb(%22bin_memory_file.

I created this .mif file from altera quartus IDE but was not aware It can not be used in $readmemh.

Comment: Yes, $readmemh uses a different format to Intel's proprietary .mif format